# Why is Data with an Overrepresented Class called Imbalanced not Unbalanced?

Tags: class-imbalance, terminology, imbalanced-data

I've seen the term *Imbalanced* used to described data that has an over-representation of one class.

What's the reasoning behind naming this type of data *Imbalanced* as opposed to *Unbalanced*, which seems to fit the intended meaning perfectly already?

Comment: I believe the two terms are used pretty much interchangeably, especially with many data scientists not speaking English as a native language. Also, statisticians are a bit perplexed with just why data scientists seem to think imbalance is a big deal: [Profusion of threads on imbalanced data - can we merge/deem canonical any?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6349/1352)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Unbalanced](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unbalanced):

> not balanced: such as
> a: not in equilibrium
> b: mentally disordered : affected with mental illness
> c: not adjusted so as to make credits equal to debits
> an unbalanced account

[Imbalanced](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/imbalanced):

> lack of balance : the state of being out of equilibrium or out of proportion
> a structural imbalance
> a chemical imbalance in the brain

**Imbalanced** is used when something is out of proportion, **Unbalanced** when you can destabilise something. Although **Imbalanced** may sometimes be more correct or the only correct word to use, I rarely see it used outside of academic circles, datasciences or similar areas.

Comment: Still seems pretty arbitrary to me. Is there a historical reason underlying the choice?